# Download of .zip file runs a corrupted file php

Tags: php, header, download, zip

I'm trying to force a download of a protected zip file  (I don't want people to access it without logging in first.

I have the function created for the `login` and such  , but I'm running into a problem where the downloaded file is corrupting.

Here's the code I have:

```
$file='../downloads/'.$filename;
header("Content-type: application/zip;\n");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-length: ".filesize($file).";\n");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");
readfile("$file");
exit();
```

Here's the error: `Cannot open file: It does not appear to be a valid archive.`

The file downloads fine otherwise, so it must be something  I'm doing wrong with the headers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This issue can have several causes. Maybe your file is not found or it can not be read and thus the file’s content is just the PHP error message. Or the HTTP header is already sent. Or you have some additional output that then corrupts your file’s content.

Try to add some error handling into your script like this:

```
$file='../downloads/'.$filename;
if (headers_sent()) {
    echo 'HTTP header already sent';
} else {
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
        echo 'File not found';
    } else if (!is_readable($file)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'File not readable';
    } else {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Gumbo! That answered it.
That was it... I think the sent headers is the reason why it wasn't working.

Comment: @Gumbo My file **does** exist, but for some reason it returns a 'File Not Found'? Any ideas?

Comment: Read message from @Pekka. It has a message inside my file. So, i get the manual PHP and a user marro at cz put --- ob_clean();  flush(); --- before the readfile(). It Works!

Answer (score 11):

I bet two beers that a PHP error occurs, and the error message messes up the ZIP file. The requested file probably doesn't exist.

Open the ZIP file with notepad or a similar text editor, and find out what's wrong.

Comment: id agree i bet there is an error in the `readfile()` like invalid permissions, or it can be found...

Comment: opening with notepad to see the error message was a life-saver. thanks man! :)

Comment: This answer gave me the idea that maybe ANY output at all (not just errors) might mess up the Zip file. Turns out my echo statements were messing it up. Removed all echo's and voila it works.

Comment: Thank you @Pekka. It has a message inside my file. So, i get the manual PHP and a user marro at cz put --- ob_clean();  flush(); --- before the readfile(). It Works!

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but maybe useful for users not being able to make `force download` work.
Add the following at the top of your `php` script

```
<?php
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems for large zip files
This works for me:

In your php.ini, change to:

- Upload_max_filesize  - 1500 M
- Max_input_time  - 1000
- Memory_limit    - 640M
- Max_execution_time -  1800
- Post_max_size - 2000 M

In your php file.

```
    $filename = "MyFile.zip";           
    $filepath='../downloads/'.$filename;    //your folder file path    
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");    
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath)); 
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"".basename($filepath)."\"");


    while (ob_get_level()) 
    {
     ob_end_clean();
     }
    readfile($filepath);   
    exit;
    ob_start ();
```

Comment: It works for me just because of "while" section. Anyway, what it means "while ob_get_level ob_end_clean"?

Comment: ob_get_level — Return the nesting level of the output buffering mechanism

ob_end_clean — Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution
create a file with name .htaccess
write below line in that
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary

upload the file to your website. If you have the file already there then please make the above change in that

Answer (score 0):

try this to find if there is any error

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Do not print anything before writing the headers;
Run an ob_start() to of your script, after the code  edit your headers and then ob_flush() and ob_clean()

Answer (score 0):

@Pekka wins 2 beer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/2088288/9294174
In my case opening terminal and reading the file using nano shown me an xdebug message...