# Downloading zip folder using php

Tags: php, download, zip

I am trying to download zip folder.

Here is my code

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename));

  $files = array('../upload/ES:AIJ_168/M:MSW.doc','../upload/ES:AIJ_168/M:MSW.pdf');



$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

readfile($zipname);
?>
```

But When I am running this script.It downloads just one empty upload folder.
I don't know why this happens.Please anyone help me out.

Comment: Did you try debugging the file, looking at it without the headers for any error messages? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Errors are: !Cannot create upload\ES:AIJ_168\M:MSW.doc
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
! Attempting to correct the invalid file name

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088267/download-of-zip-file-runs-a-corrupted-file-php?rq=1

Comment: `Attempting to correct the invalid file name` That sounds like it could be the solution. `:` isn't a valid character on Windows filesystems and I think on Macs

Comment: I tried renaming file.still same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I saw three points in your question

1) You're sending the content length before the file creation

2) When you are fetching the file size you are using `$zipfilename`, but when you open the zip file for adding files you are using `$zipname`.

3) You are using colon (`:`) in the file names. I'm not sure about this use on unix, but you can't name a file with colon on windows.

I believe that the code will be like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');    

$files = array('../upload/ES-AIJ_168/M-MSW.doc','../upload/ES-AIJ_168/M-MSW.pdf');

$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

PS.: I've used minus signs (`-`) instead of colons in the file names