# File downloaded from server is corrupted on MAC

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3

I make a script to upload file to S3 Amazon.I use this code to upload the file on S3

```
if (S3::putObject(S3::inputFile($file), $bucket, $uri, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)){ 
        echo "File Uploaded";}
```

And download that file with this code

```
 $filE=fopen('filename.zip', 'a');
    if($s3->getObject($bucket, $aws_object,$filE))

    {
    echo "File dowloaded successfully"
    fclose($filE);

    }
```

This file comes in server.From here i tried to download that file from server using these headers.

```
        $filename=basename($file);
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        readfile($file);
```

On windows file is opening proerly.But when i try to download that file on Mac .File downloaded succesfully but file name is appended with some unknown extension.supoose file name is "testing.zip",But when it download that file on MAC system the file name becomes this "testing.zip.cpgz".
I am very much worried about this.Can somebody help me.I will be very thankful to him.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download of .zip file runs a corrupted file php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088267/download-of-zip-file-runs-a-corrupted-file-php)

Comment: No that was not my issue..My file is proerly downloading on windows operating system and MAC.But on windows file is does't go corrupt while on Mac that file will be extented by cpgz extenion.

Comment: Try application/octet-stream as content type. And make sure that your filename contains .zip