# PHP Archive ZIP opens on a MAC but not windows

Tags: php, windows, zip, php-ziparchive

I have the following code that loops through image URLs and adds the images to a ZIP. It then auto downloads.

The problem I have is that it opens on my MACBook (Chrome), but not on Windows (Chrome).

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong.

[image]

```
if (array_key_exists("id", $_GET)) :
$author_id = trim($_GET["id"]);
$author_name = trim($_GET["user"]);
    $pictures = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => $author_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inheret', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    
    if ( $pictures->posts ) :
    
        # create new zip opbject
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
                    
        # create a temp file & open it
        $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
        $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    
        foreach ( $pictures->posts as $picture ) :
             if (wp_get_attachment_image_url($picture->ID, 'full')) :
            
                $files = array(wp_get_attachment_image_url( $picture->ID, 'full' ));
                if ($files) :
                    //echo $files;
                    
                    # loop through each file
                    foreach($files as $file){
                        # download file
                        $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
                        #add it to the zip
                        $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
                    
                    }
    
                endif;
            endif;
        endforeach;
        
        $zip->close();

ob_clean();
$datestamp = date("d-M-Y", time());

        # send the file to the browser as a download
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
        header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=backup-contributor-'. $author_name .'-'.$datestamp.'.zip');
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        readfile($tmp_file);
    
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: You might consider owning poc || gtfo on paperback or just read it here https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/. Easter eggs about file polyglots aside, you're probably seeing encoding variations. Moreover; when someone programs a zip encoder or decoder it may be out of date (algorithmically) or just plain wrong. Variations in encoding exists and is common. Think of word and PDF documents. Sometimes when you open them they are all wacky... Try opening with another zip utility and/or compressing with another tool.

Comment: Also consider using https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/. Your code could use some standards.

Comment: Check for errant bytes, either at the front or at the back. Whenever you call `readfile` the next line should almost always be `exit` or something to end the process and guarantee nothing else gets written

Comment: Additionally, take the actual file that is generated and manually transport it (email, USB, etc.) to a couple of computers. It is possible that the browsers are making a request in a different way which is causing the zip file to be created in an unexpected way. You can confirm this by calculating the hash of the files, too, on the client side.

Comment: @Tyler Miles Thank you for the reply and the document list standards. That will be very helpful for a newbie like myself.

Comment: @Chris-Haas - thank you for your reply. It was in fact the missing exit; after the readfile. If you add that as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as Answered to help others. Thank you again, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: @JohnKBell, there's actually a couple variations of this question and answer on the site. I think ultimately I'd close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/2088331/231316 probably